# Uitableview Cell Animation like Secret App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

Any idea, How can i implement- 
[Secret App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/secret-speak-freely/id775307543?mt=8) Settings list cell animation.

I was trying with this, but not any success because its adding all rows same time.

> [self.tableview reloadSections:sectionIndexSet
>   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

If i am inserting one by one row then this animation is not working from bottom to top animation.

Any suggestion how can i do this ?

Comment: A screen recording would be valuable here. One so that we don't have to go install the app, and two so that the question has some historic value once Secret changes their app.

Comment: i will try to add gif.Thanks Chris.

Comment: You may need to implement some animation in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this implementation:

```
//From UITableViewDelegate calls
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGRect myRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //instead of 568, choose the origin of your animation
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x,
                            cell.frame.origin.y + 568,
                            cell.frame.size.width,
                            cell.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1*indexPath.row options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        //instead of -30, choose how much you want the cell to get "under" the cell above
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(myRect.origin.x,
                                myRect.origin.y - 30,
                                myRect.size.width,
                                myRect.size.height);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            cell.frame = myRect;
        }];

    }];
}
```

Comment: i have used this code Bounce cell when scrolling fast.  Bounce and Bounce issue not proper animation cell. i want one by one add cell in fast scrolling .

Comment: Set delay as 0 and change the duration (let's say: 0.2)

Comment: ok thank you, now i want only one time animation ,when i scroll second time table at that time i don't want animation, can be possible that?

Comment: you may try to have a NSArray with the same size of your datasource and set a value (a boolean?) for those cells that have already appeared.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift-4 Version of Claudio's Answer**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let rect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)

        cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x,
                            y: cell.frame.origin.y + 568,
                            width: cell.frame.size.width,
                            height: cell.frame.size.height)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1*Double(indexPath.row), options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            cell.frame = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x,
                                y: rect.origin.y-30,
                                width: rect.width,
                                height: rect.height)
        }) { (completed) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                cell.frame = rect
            })
        }

    }
```